# How to change the cursor image in Mapbox GL JS

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

How does one change the cursor image in Mapbox GL JS? I have tried

```
#map-container {
    cursor: crosshair;
    }
but it doesn't work.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#map-container canvas {
    cursor: crosshair;
    }
where #map-container is the id of the element where your mapbox Gl JS is located.
```

or programmatically

```
map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'crosshair'
```

Comment: map.getCanvas works well for me!! thank you